# Why can I loop through a char array until NULL terminator when I didn't end the string with one?

Tags: arrays, null, char, terminator

Why is it possible to loop through this string until a NULL terminator if I did not end the string with one or give it an extra element to be automatically terminated with one?

```
char buf[5];
buf[0] = 'H';
buf[1] = 'e';
buf[2] = 'l';
buf[3] = 'l';
buf[4] = 'o';

char *p = buf;

for (p = buf; *p != '\0'; p++)
   ch_printf(ch, "%c\n", *p);
```

I am a newbie to C, attempting to teach myself, so please forgive my stupidity :)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Answer: "pure luck". It's not guaranteed to do that, and won't do it every time. Where did you allocate the buffer? If it was on the stack then wait until you've called another function and then look. If it was allocated at compile time ("data segment" as it has sometimes been called) then look what happens if you allocate another variable straight after it. And in both cases look at the difference if the bugger is 8 bytes rather than 5 - it'll *sometimes* change the behaviour. In short, don't rely on it!

Comment: I allocated it within a function, so I assume this is on the stack, right? Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are trying to access unallocated memory, therefor the result for buf[5] is null

Comment: Unallocated memory can contain anything (perhaps a result from something which was there previously). Or it could cause a memory exception and crash.